# I received a phone call from

Tags: sentence-structure, phrases

I received a phone call from the school but the call got disconnected so I want call back to ask who call me, also I think the HR department but I don’t know how to make the sentence

Comment: Give your name, then explain that you received a call from their number but were cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Important point:  In a conversation there is another person. You don't just talk you must also listen.

So you call the school. They answer the phone and say "Hello", then you say "Hello" and tell them your name. And then they ask what you want. And you respond:

> Hello, Lakeside Highschool.
>
> Hello, This is Ibrahim Gerges
>
> Good afternoon Ibrahim, how can I help you?
>
> I received a phone call from the school but the call got disconnected.
>
> I can put you though, which department was it?
>
> I think HR.
>
> ...

Now will the conversation go exactly like that? Probably not, but your English, as you used in the post is good enough to be understood by anybody who wants to understand you. You just have to listen and answer their questions.